# Problem with hibernate + maven + mysql server configuration

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have a problem with connecting to mysql database that I have created on google cloud. I easily connected mysql workbench to the database but I have a problem with configuring hibernate in my maven project. Here is the error log that shows when I want to run my application:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468)
    at org.jboss.logging@3.4.2.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2562)
    at org.jboss.logging@3.4.2.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530)
    at org.jboss.logging@3.4.2.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.7.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.7.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.7.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.<clinit>(PersistenceXmlParser.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.7.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.7.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.5.7.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at SlidingPuzzle/controllers.Main.start(Main.java:36)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application controllers.Main
```

Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>controllers</groupId>
    <artifactId>SlidingPuzzle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    
</project>
```

My module-info file:

```
module SlidingPuzzle {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.persistence;
    opens controllers to javafx.fxml;
    exports controllers;
}
```

and my main file where i try too initialize an EntityManger and EntityManagerFactory:

```
package controllers;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import models.database.User;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static Stage stage;

    public static Stage getStage(){
        return stage;
    }

    public static void setStage(Stage stage){
        Main.stage = stage;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        setStage(primaryStage);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/views/main.fxml"));
        AnchorPane anchorPane = loader.load();

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction=entityManager.getTransaction();

        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane,1024,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sliding Puzzle");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1024);
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I know that the error leads me to the moment where I try to create an EntityMAnagerFactroy but I don't know why does is show me that. Thanks for any help or a push in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps you need `requires java.sql;` in the `module-info.java` file.

Comment: @jewelsea Sadly, it didn't work, but the error message changed to "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named manager1". But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, the last error was caused by a stupid spelling error in the persistence.xml file name. But the new error that I get now is: "net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver".

Comment: Ok, I resolved that error by adding "requires net.bytebuddy;" to the module-info.java. The next error i get is: "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/classmate/TypeResolver". I hope I am near the end.

Comment: Your issue from your stack trace is that you have not listed all of the required modules.  Continue to update your module-info.java to include the required modules.  There may be other unrelated errors that you need to fix (such as your persistence configuration mentioned earlier) in order for your project to work, but StackOverflow questions are usually limited to a single, focused question and answer topic, so addressing all of your potential issues here is out of scope for a StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need `requires java.sql;` in the `module-info.java` file in order to make use of the features of the java.sql module.

For more information, see a [java 9 module tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

There are likely other required modules that you will need to add to your module-info specification in order to get your application to work.